# BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job Unexpected. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm having problem to extract data from bigquery to cloud storage, I´ve set a public read -write permissions on Cloud Storage, but I always receive this:

BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job Unexpected. Please try again.

the command I'm executing is with bq client tool:

bq extract dummy_dev.users gs://dummy_dev/some.json

Is this a known issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uhm... suddenly it´s working now, without any code changes. weird.

Comment: now its failing again , agile-kite-497:bqjob_r7687d657cafc7a39_000001447e07a5bb_1 , and the message is ambiguous, hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

Were streaming inserts used to populate the data in the table being extracted? If so, this may be related to the difference in [data durability](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#datadurability) for streaming data and the nature of how streaming data is buffered prior to full replication.